# Android: Camera not closing after accepting taken picture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

we have a camera intent with an extra output. Code below:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        System.out.println("onActivityResult called");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            StorageController.readCardImage(activity,activity.getCurrentCard().getUUID());
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        }
    }
    public void startCamera(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(StorageController.createCardImageFile(activity, activity.getCurrentCard().getUUID())));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);

    }
```

The intent is starting (camera opening) and we are able to take a picture.
But when we try to accept the taken picture (pressing check-button), the camera does not return to the starting activity. We are getting no errors.

What could possibly be the reason for this?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: did you tried to debug onActivityResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could possibly be the reason for this?

The camera app that you are testing with has bugs. [This happens](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` delegates to any one of hundreds of camera apps, based on device and user. Some of those apps' developers do not test `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` very well.

There is nothing that you can do about this, other than not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.